# How to import ZeroEx npm module in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have to install [this](https://0xproject.com/docs/0x.js#installation) library

```
npm install 0x.js --save
```

and make the ZeroEx variable globally available in my ember app. 
I tried this but it doesn't work. ZeroEx is undefined.

**app/controllers/application.js**

```
import { ZeroEx } from 'npm:0x.js';
console.log(ZeroEx)
```

> **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

You have to do some extra work to use a plain npm module in Ember. You can either do the hard work yourself by following the instructions in the Ember guide (https://guides.emberjs.com/release/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_compiling-assets) or you can make use of the relatively new Ember add-on `ember-auto-import`, which will hopefully do a lot of the hard work for you. You can find instructions on how to use `ember-auto-import` here: https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import

However, to save you having to click through, this is all you should have to do:

```
ember install ember-auto-import
npm install 0x.js --save-dev
```

and then you should be able to do this:

```
import { ZeroEx } from '0x.js';
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: I tried importing from controllers/application.js but "ZeroEx" is still undefined.

Comment: Hmm... it could be that 0x.js is a special case. If you're still having problems, you could try posting an issue to https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import.